# how can I input log4j2's logs into ByteBuffer in java?

Tags: maven, log4j2, spring-boot-starter

I'm trying to upload local logs generated by log4j2 to AWS S3 bucket without storing logs in my local.

I want to make log4j2's logs transfer to S3 bucket directly.

The method what I think is putting console logs to ByteBuffer, and upload to S3 bucket using by AWS JAVA sdk v2.

here is my code.

```
package com.ibiz.logging;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class S3LoggingApplication {

    // log instance create
    final static Logger logs = LogManager.getLogger(S3LoggingApplication.class);




    // why has to use string[] args?
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        // log gen
        logs.info("Log Gen Start!!!");
        logs.info("Log Gen Start!!!");
        logs.info("Log Gen Start!!!");
        logs.info("Log Gen Start!!!");
        Long started = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // loop for 3 min
        // while (now - started < TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(3)) {
        //     logs.info("You knock kncok mineral!");
        //     logs.warn("We are under attack!!");
        //     logs.error("Nuclear launch detected!!");
        //     logs.trace("GG");
        //     // term 7 sec
        //     Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(7));
        // }
        // stream
        // InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream();        

        // input byte buffer        
        // ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap();

        // log gotcha


        // upload
        // S3Client s3 = S3Client.create();
        // TODO upload function

        // s3.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket("jk.test").key("jk").build(), RequestBody.fromByteBuffer(byteBuffer));
}
}
```

Comment: You might try using something like the [SocketAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SocketAppender)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. SocketAppender, You are right. But S3 doesn't have IP exposed, right? To use Socket networking, I have to know ip address or port, doesn't it?